# M1 Mac, There is no Java folder in library folder

Tags: java

I bought M1 MacBook Pro first in this time.

I downloaded JDK 18 for Mac, and I tried to set up the environment variable.

But I can't find /library/java folder.

I found library folder, but there is no java folder in there.

Somebody plz help me...

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `which java` and `/usr/libexec/java_home`

Comment: Also it's not `/library/java` it's `/Library/Java`

Comment: I entered which java in terminal, and output was /usr/bin/java

Comment: @Odriv Yes, hence why the next suggestion by @Karthikeyan was: .. and now run `/usr/libexec/java_home`. Which tells you what `/usr/bin/java` actually ends up doing.

Comment: I runed /usr/libexec/java_home. Am I done now?

Comment: Oh, I just have found the JAVA folder. Thanks for helping me!

Comment: @Odriv where was the java folder?

Comment: Macintosh HD/Library/Java.